# VBA Excel variables value after closing the excel file

Tags: vba, excel

I have an user form which selects a directory path. That path is stored in a variable. The problem is that every time I start the macro, I have to rechoose the path for the directory. How should be the path variable declared in order to keep it's value once the macro is closed, or the excel file is closed ?

Comment: `Dim myPath as String` and then hardcode the path ie. `myPath = "C:\Users\username\Desktop\myFile.xlsx"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Persisting data between calls to a macro is simpler; use a variable at module scope in the `.bas` module containing the macro.

Persisting data on saving is more difficult. You could write to the registry but that's tricky and you'll need to use various Windows API functions.

The simplest thing to do would be to write the data to somewhere on the workbook.

Comment: I want data to be loaded automatically at the start of the excel file  without pressing a button to load the data from the workbook

Comment: To do that, implement `Workbook_Open` (Google that for more details) and rip the data from the workbook to your data variables there. Avoid the registry route if possible.

Answer (score 1):

The registry is simple in VBA. It's is very limited and uses ini file concepts.

There's a few of them such as (from Object Browser [F2] in VBA editor)

```
Function GetAllSettings(AppName As String, Section As String)
    Member of VBA.Interaction

Sub SaveSetting(AppName As String, Section As String, Key As String, Setting As String)
    Member of VBA.Interaction

Sub DeleteSetting(AppName As String, [Section], [Key])
    Member of VBA.Interaction

Function GetSetting(AppName As String, Section As String, Key As String, [Default]) As String
    Member of VBA.Interaction
```

Also the newer Windows Scripting Host Shell object also makes registry access easy.

```
object.RegDelete(strName)

object.RegRead(strName) 

object.RegWrite(strName, anyValue [,strType])
```

Also WMI can access registry. Unlike both above methods it can ennumerate, so you can see what is there without have to know in advance.

```
Dim proglist()
Set oReg=GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\.\root\default:StdRegProv")
ret = oReg.EnumKey(&H80000002, "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall", proglist)
If err.num =0 then
   For each prog in proglist
        msgbox prog
   Next
Else
    Msgbox err.num & " " & err.description & " " & err.source
    err.clear
End If
```

It can also check security and monitor changes to keys.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a Name, which can be saved with the workbook.

```
 ThisWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="SavedPath", RefersTo:= someString
```

Another simple alternative is to put that value in a cell, eventually in a hidden sheet, or a hidden row/column of any suitable sheet.

A third solution is to add it to the file properties.

Registry tricks are complex, don't work if you change machine or if user has not enough rights.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem storing the data on a cell and then on excel file initialization giving the data to corresponding variables. Thank you very much for those who thought to a solution !